# Something is not right with my input and if-else statements,

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

I'm trying to print out an ISBN number, a user types in 10 numbers, and the program will check if the following conditions are correct: input is only numbers, input is 10 letters long. that's it.

Problem: No matter what, the 'if' statement wont run. Even if my input is "1234567899" <= 10 letters. So far, I can't see what the problem is.

I probably made a really stupid mistake.... :(

EDIT: I don't know why, but I don't seem to be able to access ary[0], ary[1] and so on in the if statement. I get 'java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1' error message. Am i accessing it wrong?

I have found out that, String[] ary = svar.split(" "); IS not working as intended. ary only has one element, the whole damn input. I wanted to split every character in the input and store each integer in the input into a single element in array ary, that's why I'm getting this error.

```
import java.util.*;
class isIntegerclass{
    public static boolean isValid(String s) {
        try { 
            Integer.parseInt(s); 
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) { 
            return false; }
        return true;
    }
}

class ISBNcheck {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter input: "); //ask for input
        String svar = input.nextLine(); // read input

        if (isIntegerclass.isValid(svar) && svar.length() == 9) {
            String[] ary = svar.split(" ");//put the numbers in string 'svar' into array called ary.
            System.out.println("True: ");

            // accessing elements in array
            System.out.println(" " + ary[0] + " - " + ary[1] + " " + ary[2] + " " + ary[3] + " - " + ary[4] + " " + ary[5] + " " + ary[6] + " " + ary[7] + " " + ary[8] + " - " + ary[9]); //print
        } else {
            System.out.println("This is not the right input...");
            System.out.println("The number must be 10 letters(numbers only) long. No need for dashes in between.");
            System.out.println("[] - [][][] - [][][][][] - []");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Input a number 123456789 i.e 9 digits you will see your syso statement getting printed :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> m: No matter what, the 'if' statement wont run. Even if my input is "1234567899" <= 10 letters. So far, I can't see what the problem is.

because you are accepting only 9 character `String`, and expecting it to work for 10 character (`1234567899`) `String`

```
svar.length() == 9
```

Comment: Thank you! i assumed the length of a string worked the same way as an array's length (starting at 0). thanks :)

Comment: An array's length doesn't start at 0, it starts at 1. It's only an array's indices which start at 0. For example, `new String[10].length == 10`

Comment: I don't suppose you can help with the array problem? :(

Answer (score 3):

Please do not rely on exceptions for normal program flow, they should be used for exceptional situations.

Why not use this instead?

```
private static boolean isValidISBN(String s) {
    return s.matches("^[0-9]{10}$");
}
```

EDIT: Perhaps I need to explain. `"^[0-9]{10}$"` is a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression). `^` stands for the start of the string, `$` for the end. `[0-9]` means any digit, and `{10}` is the count of digits.

Comment: I have to ask, why would you make this method private? just wondering. I need to access the boolean in my if statement.

Comment: It is intended to be part of the class that contains your if-statement. If you need it from other classes, just make it public.